# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, mapstruct

I need help with the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [D:\projects\PIK\bin\main\edu\pw\eiti\pik\user\UserController.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at edu.pw.eiti.pik.PikApplication.main(PikApplication.java:10) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:79) ~[mapstruct-jdk8-1.2.0.Final.jar:na]
    at edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserMapper.getInstance(UserMapper.java:12) ~[main/:na]
    at edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserController.<init>(UserController.java:18) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for edu.pw.eiti.pik.user.UserMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:93) ~[mapstruct-jdk8-1.2.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:76) ~[mapstruct-jdk8-1.2.0.Final.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

UserMapper interface has

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
```

annotation.
I use eclipse Neon with buildship plugin, org.mapstruct and spring are imported with Gradle.
It works without this error on my colleague's IntelliJ

Code for UserMapper:

```
package edu.pw.eiti.pik.user;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface UserMapper {

    static UserMapper getInstance() {
        return Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    }

    User fromDto(UserDto dto);

    UserDto toDto(User entity);

    Authority fromDto(AuthorityDto dto);

    AuthorityDto toDto(GrantedAuthority entity);
}
```

From what I read it could do something with compiler failing to connect auto-generated code (Gradle does not set anything in AnnotationProcessing>FactoryPath)

Comment: no, Mapper is the only annotation

Comment: it is actually an interface, my bad.

Comment: I tried adding it to

`static UserMapper getInstance() {
        return Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    }`

but to no effect

Comment: No, I do not use `@Autowired`

Comment: However it works without modification on my colleague's IntelliJ

Comment: Only default constructor

Comment: There is no class implementing UserMapper

Comment: Do you use the apt plugin? If yes which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found probable cause:

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1159

looks like an issue between mapstruct and lombok

Edit:

Solution is to remove javaagent:lombok.jar from eclipse.ini, restart IDE and rebuild project, make a copy of files generated from annotation, add javaagent to eclipse.ini, restart IDE and rebuild project and restore copied files

Answer (score 5):

Add annotation mapstruct and lombok processors to your compiler plugin and mapstruct should generate implementation for your mapper interface:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: You save my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

When using Mapstruct with Spring, you can define that the mapper should generate a Spring bean using `componentModel` as described in [2. Set up. 2.4 Configuration options](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#configuration-options).

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
    /* your code... */
}
```

This allows you to inject the mapper in your beans:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    //rest of your code...
}
```

Take into account that Mapstruct generates the code on precompile stage, so you won't see any class implementing `UserMapper` interface until you compile the code and see the generated code folder.

Comment: @J.Łyskawa how are you running your app?

Comment: `SpringApplication.run(PikApplication.class, args);`

Comment: Are you including the package where your mapper is located as part of the spring auto scanning?